# Custom post type custom taxonomy archive page name

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

How archive php file should be named?

Url:

mypage.com/gallerycategory/sport/

`gallerycategory` - slug of custom taxonomy of custom post type (name of custom taxonomy is `gallery_categories` with slug `gallerycategory`)

`'sport'` - one of terms (categories) of `gallerycategory` .

Currently this page hits `archive.php` file, but I need to create specific file for this pattern ('gallerycategory'/'customtaxonomyterm').

Here is how I register:

```
 $labels = array(
        'name' => __('VmGallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN, THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
        'singular_name' => __('VmGallery', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
        ...
    );
    $supports = array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ...);
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => 'VM galleries',
        'public' => true,
        'supports' => $supports,
        'taxonomies' => array('gallery_categories', 'post_tag'),            
        'has_archive' => 'gallery'
    );

    register_post_type('vmgallery', $args);


register_taxonomy(
    'gallery_categories', 'VmGallery', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => __('Categories', THEME_TEXT_DOMAIN),
        'query_var' => true,            
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'gallerycategory',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the archive index for a custom taxonomy, you would use taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php template file. So, if you've created a custom taxonomy, gallery-exhibitions, the archive index for this taxonomy would use the taxonomy-gallery-exhibitions.php template file.

If you need the archive index for terms for your custom taxonomy, you would use taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php template file. So, if you've got a term, future-exhibitions, for your custom taxonomy, the archive index for this term would be taxonomy-gallery-exhibitions-future-exhibitions.php.

(Note: I'm not sure how hyphenated taxonomy and term slugs will impact the template hierarchy; it shouldn't, but if you run into problems, you might try using single-word terms for taxonomy and term.)

Comment: Change the rewrite slug of register texonomy and then create the page of this name it will working..